# Examples for com.google.gwt.app.place from GWT 2.1

Tags: java, gwt

The com.google.gwt.app.place package is new in GWT 2.1 which came out yesterday. Do you have any example on that API? How do I effectively use it? The GWT samples does't help at all.

Comment: The only instance of Place.java I see in the current source tree is in the bikeshed (example) app -- http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#A1edwVHBClQ/bikeshed/src/com/google/gwt/app/place/Place.java&q=Place%20package:http://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc -- it may not be entirely ready to use (i.e., not in the "real" source tree) yet. After all, it's only been about 24 hours since it was announced. I expect there will be fuller docs in the next few days/weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen Place used is in the scaffolding generated by the GWT plugin for Spring Roo.

If you want to generate a quick app to take a look:

start the roo console

```
>project --topLevelPackage com.testapp.test
>gwt setup
```

Then have a look at the generated code in the com.testapp.test.gwt.scaffold package.